# what do the rocks in the cave mean in candy box 2

Tags: candy-box-2

I have been in the cave for so long and I still can't figure out what the rocks mean. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the cave, in Candy Box 2 you will see a bunch of strange rock formations on the ground. The "o"s should resemble trees on the overworld map. And the X is a place you should click, it will allow you to obtain 3 chocolate bars.

On the way to the [heart plug](https://candybox2.fandom.com/wiki/Heart_plug), you must keep going straight until you see a tiny arrow on the wall. Keep following them and do not mistake other symbols for the arrow and eventually, you will come across it.